# Given A is a nil-potent matrix (given $ A^k=0 $), prove that A-I is invertible. Is my proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, solution-verification, nilpotence

> Given $A$ is a nil-potent matrix (given $A^k=0$), prove that A-I is invertible.

I have proved the statement using contradiction, and I want to know if it is correct:

Let $ A-I \neq I.$ 
 
Multiplying by $ A^{k-1} $ on both sides , we get:
$$A^k - A^{k-1} \neq A^{k-1},$$ but since $A^k=0$,
we get $ -A^{k-1} \neq A^{k-1}.$ Multiplying by A on both sides on left we get $0 \neq 0$, which is a contradiction. 
Is this a correct way of proving this? I have a doubt because we are basically multiplying 0 on both sides, without showing it explicitly here.

Comment: No, this is not correct. $\neq$ does not work like $=$, it's not guaranteed that identical manipulations of both sides of such an inequality will preserve inequality.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108143/inverse-of-a-unipotent-matrix).

Comment: The error is more severe than what Matt mentions above, you seem to think that the negation of '$A-I$ being invertible' is $A-I\neq I$.

Comment: @GitGud So what will the negation of $A-I$ not being invertible be ?

Comment: '$A-I$ is invertible' is $\exists B((A-I)B=I=B(A-I))$, negate this to get the negation.

Comment: @GitGud Wow, you are great !

Comment: Your sarcasm made me laugh.

Comment: @GitGud no sarcasm. My thought process is right now filled with the statement you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is incorrect. For one thing, $A - I \neq I$ is not the negation of $A- I $ being invertible. For another thing, it is unclear if multiplying by $A^{k-1}$ preserves the inequality.

There are several ways to show what you are trying to show. One is to observe that $A$, being nilpotent, cannot have $1$ as eigenvalue, another would be to simply write down the inverse to this end start by factoring $I - A^k$.

Comment: What will be the statement of negation of A-I being invertible?

Comment: There are several ways. One close to what you have would be $(A-I)B \neq I$ for *all* $B$.

Answer (score 3):

So consider following equation: $$I = I-\underbrace{A^k}_0 = (I+A+A^2+\ldots+A^{k-1})\cdot (I-A)$$ Therefore $(I-A)$ is invertible because we have an explicit inverse:

$$(I-A)^{-1} = I+A+A^2+\ldots+A^{k-1}$$

or

$$(A-I)^{-1} = -(I+A+A^2+\ldots+A^{k-1})$$

Comment: This does not answer the question: "Is this a correct way of proving this?"

Comment: What question do you refer to? EDIT: Ok it the original question has been altered...

Comment: It contained that question definitely before you submitted your answer. It is in the first version; actually I doubt is was ever not there.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work, because you don't have cancelation in the world of matrices: just because $AC=BC$ does not mean that $A=B$, even if $C\neq 0$.  However, here is a hint that might get you to a proof.

Consider the power series $$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Let A is nilpotent matrix, s.t A^n=0 for some n

Consider another matrix

$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}-A^{j}$

multiply these two martices,

$(A-I)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}-A^j$ =$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}-A^{j+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}A^j$

$=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}A^{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}A^j$

$=-A^n-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}A^{j}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}A^j+A^0$

$=I$

Therefore $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}-A^{j}$ is inverse for A-I